# Trouble with HTML Image Map Coordinates

Tags: html, image, imagemap

As the title indicates, I am having trouble with my HTML Image Map Coordinates. I am new to this and I am building a web page for a college class that I'm enrolled. This is extremely important I figure this out because I don't want to keep get points knocked off for something that isn't even widely used on the internets anymore

I've created five news links on my college project web page all linked to npr.org news articles. I used the images from their pages as the image map links on my page. I also have each headline linked to the npr.org articles.

My image maps are mean't to surround the news article images on my page. However, I don't know how to properly locate the coordinates on the web page. As you can see below I've only included coordinates for two of the images but when you click on the second image it takes you to the article that is linked to first image.

My teacher told me I can use Gimp to find the coordinates for each image but how does using Gimp find the coordinates on the web page itself. The coordinates I found for each image using online image map generators don't work at all. AHHHHH! This doesn't make sense to me, I'm getting really frustrated and I want to start pulling my hair out!

Can anyone help me, please!

**-- Image Map HTML code --**

```
    <div class="left">
        <section class="left">

            <h2 id="header_2">News</h2>
            <hr />
            <article class="news">
                <h3><a href="http://www.npr.org/sections/therecord/2015/08/19/432774407/a-rational-conversation-does-anybody-even-have-time-for-an-80-minute-album">A Rational Conversation: Does Anybody Even Have Time for an 80 minute Album?</a></h3>
                    <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2015/08/19/gettyimages-478840556-63f8a45a4271d0d9e6728e6689adab1fe218a2ee-s800-c85.jpg" style= "width: 45%" usemap="#newsmap" />
                <h3><a href="http://www.npr.org/sections/microphonecheck/2015/07/29/424717271/large-professor-part-1-were-living-in-the-world-of-hip-hop">Large Professor, Part 1: 'Were Living in the World of Hip-Hop'</a></h3>
                    <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2015/07/23/gettyimages-167826838_wide-46b6a9a598bfc3376df9c71f9a3cd281362c8319-s800-c85.jpg" style= "width: 45%" usemap="#newsmap" />
                <h3><a href="http://www.npr.org/2015/08/11/426758835/music-journalist-chronicles-the-wild-obsessive-hunt-for-rare-78-rpm-records">Music Journalist Chronicles The 'Wild Obessive Hunt for Rare 78 RPM Records'</a></h3>
                    <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2015/08/11/amanda-petrusich-author-photo-credit-to-bret-stetka-_wide-3c9fe52c75a15196fa3ed0781c6674d5813552b2-s400-c85.jpg" style="width: 45%" usemap="#newsmap" />
                <h3><a href="http://www.npr.org/sections/therecord/2015/06/03/411665500/12-essential-archives-for-internet-era-music-historians">12 Essential Archives for Internet-Era Music Historians</a></h3>
                    <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2015/06/03/2000_brick-c008578a10c9f60512fa3bf1c0a73ec3f33d4d3f-s800-c85.jpg" style="width: 45%" usemap="#newsmap" />
                <h3><a href="http://www.npr.org/2015/06/29/417426717/npr-musics-25-favorite-albums-of-2015-so-far">NPR Music's 25 Favorite Albums of 2015 (So Far)</a></h3>
                    <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2015/06/28/albumart_wide-30e77b7db33df7b858c8b3c50508bc60dca0e25c-s400-c85.jpg" style="width: 45%" usemap="#newsmap" />
            </article>

            <!-- Image map for news pictures.

            I had trouble finding the coordinates for each picture on my web page so I included the image maps to show that I new how to code them in. I left the coordinates in for the first two image maps, connected to the first two news pictures, to show that when you click on the second photo, it still sends you to the page from the first article. -->

            <map name="newsmap">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1, 0, 215, 159" style="outline: none" href="http://www.npr.org/sections/therecord/2015/08/19/432774407/a-rational-conversation-does-anybody-even-have-time-for-an-80-minute-album" />
                <area shape="circle" coords="109, 62, 10" style="outline: none" href="http://www.npr.org/sections/microphonecheck/2015/07/29/424717271/large-professor-part-1-were-living-in-the-world-of-hip-hop" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="" style="outline: none" href="http://www.npr.org/2015/08/11/426758835/music-journalist-chronicles-the-wild-obsessive-hunt-for-rare-78-rpm-records" />
                <area shape="circle" coords="" style="outline: none" href="http://www.npr.org/sections/therecord/2015/06/03/411665500/12-essential-archives-for-internet-era-music-historians" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="" style="outline: none" href="http://www.npr.org/2015/06/29/417426717/npr-musics-25-favorite-albums-of-2015-so-far" />
            </map>

        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with image maps but they are fairly ancient technology. Perhaps you could use another approach, e.g. a number of independent PNG images (with transparency where needed) positioned using CSS's `position: absolute`?

Comment: Oh, I see now you apparently *have* to use it as part of your assignment, hmmmmm

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, you guess correctly. I can't get around using them, they have to be included. This is what is driving me insane! I know there's nothing fundamentally wrong, I just read that they aren't really used anymore. Thanks Pekka.

Comment: Yeah. Re your problem, there may be a misunderstanding here: an image map is applied to *one* giant picture. The coordinates within each area are relative to the *image's* top left corner.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, what is wrong is that it seems you have individual image files, that all refer to the same image map `newsmap`, but this is not the way image maps are used.

If you already have individual images as you have, which you just want clicked on, and each images goes somewhere appropriate to that individual image, then you might as well wrap each use of `img` in a hyperlink `a` in this pattern: `<a href="http://link1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>`, and next image could be `<a href="http://link2"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>` etc, there would be no reason to use HTML image maps feature on individual separate image files.

Image maps are of a scenario where you want to have a single image file, and instead of doing the above having to work with separate image files, you want to just take a single image file, and define clickable regions, so that the user can click a region and go to the url defined for that region.

So firstly, although I can answer your technical question on how to do either, you could still fail on the assignment if you did the wrong solution. What did your teacher actually ask for? For example:

- students are to create a web page and demonstrate they can, using multiple images, have images link to a different page

or

- students are to create a web page and demonstrate they know how to take a single image and define clickable regions via the image map feature

You have to be sure of what your assignment actually was.

If the assignment was an image map, then yes it makes some sense:

> My teacher told me I can use Gimp to find the coordinates for each image but how does using Gimp find the coordinates on the web page itself.

No, image maps aren't about using coordinates of the web page itself, but instead are coordinates of the image itself, hence why you would use GIMP.

Although your document doesn't specify document type, so browsers will probably interpret your page as pre-html5 but whether it is html4 or html5, image map coordinates are never of the whole web page, but relative to the top left of your actual image.

html4 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.6.1

> *Coordinates are relative to the top, left corner of the object.* All values are lengths. All values are separated by commas.

html5 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-area-element

> In the rectangle state, area elements must have a coords attribute with exactly four integers, the first of which must be less than the third, and the second of which must be less than the fourth. The four points must represent, respectively, *the distance from the left edge of the image to the left side of the rectangle, the distance from the top edge to the top side, the distance from the left edge to the right side, and the distance from the top edge to the bottom side,* all in CSS pixels.

Although I'm using an older version of GIMP, 2.8.2 from 2013, it should still be the same, wherever the cursor is, the bottom left status bar of the screen indicates image coordinates, and it is always `0,0` at the top left just as you need it to be, to obtain the coordinates used for html image map code.

> but when you click on the second image it takes you to the article that is linked to first image.

Because:

- you have a first image saying "my image map is defined by `newsmap`".
- Then the second image says me too, "my image map is defined by `newsmap`".
- but image map feature was never meant for multiple images to share the same image map definition
- so the image map `newsmap` defines several regions. The top left corner region goes to `80-minute-album` page.
- so when clicking the first image's top left corner, it refers to `newsmap` and recognizes Oh, clicking here means go to the `80-minute-album` page
- but clicking the second image's top left corner, because it also refers to `newsmap`, it just thinks Oh, top left corner means go to the `80-minute-album` page.
- thus why you have an occurrence of the first and second images going to the same page

To fix this again you have to double check what the teacher's instructions were.

If the teacher really just wanted the most reasonable navigation with multiple separate images, I'd recommend the wrapping of individual images in its own link as suggested earlier.

But if you are certain you are to do image maps then you need to first figure out what big, single image to use, and then define the image map and its clickable regions.

Comment: What an insanely detailed answer! Nice!

Comment: Right on my man, thanks for the feedback user454038! I've gotta email my teacher to get the specifics from him again and then I'll post here.